# Can I run Durandal's Tests Framework outside of PhantomJS?

Tags: testing, phantomjs, durandal

The [Durandal Test Framework](https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/tree/master/test) runs Jasmine tests within PhantomJS.

Where I'm implementing this for the first time I'm getting a lot of errors, and reading through these on the command prompt is proving to be very tedious.

If I load up the spec.html file in my web browser, it tells me that no specs were found:

> [image: No Specs Found; browser screenshot]

Yet PhantomJS is able to find the specs with no problem:

> [image: 64 specs, 1 failure; PhantomJS view]

Is there a way I can configure these Jasmine tests to run through my web browser and not through (or as well as) PhantomJS?

---

I've set up a new `index.html` file and have replaced the `var runTests = ...` section with a simple `require()` call:

```
require(['../test/specs/system.spec.js']);
```

Durandal's `system.spec.js` file is loaded in the browser, but Jasmine is still stating that no specs were found.

Answer (score 0):

Jasmine's tests weren't being run because I wasn't telling it to re-execute. The solution to this was to simply re-execute by calling this within the require callback:

```js
require(['../test/specs/system.spec.js'], function() {
  jasmine.getEnv().execute();
});
```

---

*Note: A drawback of this is that the 'no specs found' bar is still present and the 'raise exceptions' control on the re-executed specs doesn't appear to function:*

[image: Screenshot of issue described above]